# I did not start with 101 rep on a new site, despite doing so before

Tags: support, linked-accounts, association-bonus

I came originally from SO and I know when I joined SF, SU, and programmers.SE, I started with 101 rep with a gracious in-network bonus - or whatever y'all call it. I recently joined outdoors.SE and was surprised that I didn't start with the boost I had on other sites so members wouldn't treat me as completely new.

It's been a while since I was active on SO or other sites so it could have something to do with that but not sure. Did this change?

Answer (score 7):

Well - *this* is a new account. Searching for your username (which is a public thing) turns up [another, older account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/174744/m-babcock) with the same name - which could indicate the issue you have.

*This* account has less than 200 reputation everywhere and doesn't have the association bonus, the old one did.

You can use the [contact](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) link to request a merger between the two accounts if its you.

Comment: Thanks so much. No idea why _this_ account was suggested on the login page when I'm still logged in on the right one on SO.

Comment: Ah! Mystery solved then. I have theories, but most of them are based on non public information. Requesting a merge *should* sort it out I suspect. I'm not sure why it would suggest an alternate credential but there you go